# Rails - How do you create members that are part of a has_many relationship dynamically when creating the parent?

Tags: javascript, ruby-on-rails, linux

So in a rails app I have a table in my database, hard drives, and for each hard drive I have a variable number of heads and platters. When I create or edit the hard drive, I want to either a) display dynamically the number of head status and platter status forms that are needed or b) route the user to a page that has the appropriate number of head and status forms continuously on the page. I favor option a, but I think it will require some custom javascript or something in order for it to work (not really feasible unless there is a plugin, I don't know javascript). Really, I want to reject any hard drive that not have it's platter and head statuses entered.

(variable names are of course hard_drive, platter_status, and head_status)

For an example, if I have a laptop drive, I want to define that it has 1 head and platter while creating the drive. Either when the value in the combobox for the head & platter count changes, display the form for the platter & head status. When the create button is hit, it should use the data to create the hard_drive in the database, and each of the platter_status and head_status items as appropriate.

How do I do this? I know that in the view, I have to add something that will detect the change in the combo box and display the layout using the value from the combobox.

It is similar in nature to [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9613750/dynamically-change-form-based-on-value-selected-in-combobox-in-ruby-on-rails)

---

**Edit 1:**
So, I have [this](https://gist.github.com/2985239), and so far it's not working, but I have the right idea. I stumbled upon some threads that talk about using javascript to dynamically add html.

```
  <div class="field" id="head_count" >
    <label for="hard_drive_head_count">Head count</label><br />
    <input id="hard_drive_head_count" name="hard_drive[head_count]" type="number" value="0" />
    <script type="text/javascript">
      var input = document.getElementById('hard_drive_head_count'),
        events = [
        "input",
         ];
      events.map(function(ev) {
      input.addEventListener(ev, function() {
        console.log(ev + ' => ' + input.value);
    if (parseInt(input.value) === 1) {
      document.getElementById('platter_statuses').innerHTML= "howdy";
    } else {
      document.getElementById('platter_statuses').innerHTML="";
    }
      }, false);
      });
    </script>
  </div>
  <label for="platter_status">Platter status</label><br />
  <div class="field" id="platter_statuses" >

  </div>
```

Now that I have this however, the question moves to - how can I populate this quickly with the forms from the _form.html.erb for the platter_status views, with the stuff all filled in from the database as it should?
I thought about in the else, using some dynamic ruby, but I don't know exactly how to pass an argument (the platter number and the drive id) so that the database knows what to populate it with, and I don't know what to put after the @ in <%= @SOMETHING_HERE %> so that it resolves to the platter_status view...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I actually found that there is a helper that is great for what I needed. It's the accepts_nested_attributes_for function in the model. This, combined with rails cast 196 and 197 helped me achieve exactly what I wanted.

In the hard_drive model, you should have a:

```
attr_accessible :head_statuses_attributes
has_many :head_statuses, :dependent => :destroy
accepts_nested_attributes_for :head_statuses, :allow_destroy => true
```

for the head_status and platter_status models.

In the view, you'll need a line like this:

```
<%= link_to_add_fields "add head status", f, :head_status %>
```

and in the partial outside of any  tag, you'll need a:

```
 <%= link_to_remove_fields "Remove", f %>
```

For more information, see these articles:
[how accepts_nested_attributes_for works](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4485507/rails-3-how-does-accepts-nested-attributes-for-work)

[How the dynamic editing is possible](http://railscasts.com/episodes/196-nested-model-form-part-1)
[How the dynamic editing is possible part 2](http://railscasts.com/episodes/197-nested-model-form-part-2)